# Does each volcano have a fingerprint?

Tags: geochemistry, volcanology, magmatism

Thinking about arc volcanism in a region, and there are two neighboring composite volcanoes 50 km apart from each other.

Do you expect any differences about their products (lavas, pyroclastic deposits)?
Does each volcano have a fingerprint property?

Possibly a geochemical difference...